# MySQL Query - Sum data according to Category Parent name - each their own column

Tags: mysql, join, sum

Here is the data I have:

table `agencies`:

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 18 | agency_01 |
| 6 | agency_02 |

table `compensations`

| id | agency_id | compensation_category_id | amount | registered_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 | 4 | 45000.00 | 2023-01-01 |
| 4 | 6 | 5 | 25000.00 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | 18 | 4 | 47000.00 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | 18 | 5 | 10000.00 | 2023-01-01 |

table `compensation_categories`

| id | parent_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | COMPENSATION |
| 2 | null | DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT |
| 3 | null | INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT |
| 4 | 1 | PERSONEL_COST |
| 5 | 1 | FIXED_COMPENSATION |

The following code show the correct result:

```
SELECT a.code,
       SUM(c.amount) AS total_amount
FROM agencies a
LEFT JOIN compensations c ON a.id = c.agency_id
WHERE DATE(c.registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY a.code;
```

result:

| code | total_amount |
| --- | --- |
| agency_01 | 57000.00 |
| agency_02 | 70000.00 |

while this code does not work:

```
SELECT a.code,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN cc.name = 'COMPENSATION' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS COMPENSATION,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN cc.name = 'DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN cc.name = 'INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT
FROM agencies a
LEFT JOIN compensations c ON a.id = c.agency_id
LEFT JOIN compensation_categories cc ON cc.id = c.compensation_category_id
WHERE DATE(c.registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY a.code;
```

result:

| code | COMPENSATION | DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT | INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| agency_01 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| agency_02 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

The amounts from the first query should fall under "COMPENSATION" column of the second query, but it shows zero. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT a.code,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'COMPENSATION' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS COMPENSATION,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT
FROM agencies a
LEFT JOIN compensations c ON a.id = c.agency_id
LEFT JOIN compensation_categories cc ON cc.id = c.compensation_category_id
LEFT JOIN compensation_categories parent ON parent.id = cc.parent_id
WHERE DATE(c.registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY a.code;
```